# Haskell FFI - can you obtain a C Pointer from a Haskell data structure?

Tags: c, haskell, ffi

I have quite a few C structs structured like

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
} StructA;
```

And a lot of functions like

```
void doSomethingWith(StructA*,StructB*,StructC*);
```

Is there an easy way to call these functions with Haskell FFI? Like, is there something that behaves like the & operator in C? (I imagine there isn't, but if there was I'd like to know). Do I *have* to make the Haskell side `data`'s instance of storeable (I don't have any constructor functions for these structs).

Also: If I have to pass a struct instead of a struct pointer (not a hypothetical question, I have a few functions like that - it's not my code so I can't do anything about it), can I just pass the components of the struct instead? Like if I want to call

```
void function(StructA);
```

can I do this with

```
foreign import ccall "function" :: CUInt -> CUInt -> IO()
```

?

Comment: Some more details are needed -- since yes, the FFI lets you pass things by pointer or value. Are the StructA* pointing at Haskell or C data?

Comment: Haskell data. Basically, I have `data A = A CUInt CUInt CUInt` and want to use that as an argument to the C function expecting a StructA*.

Comment: No wait, I misread your question. The StructA*'s are pointers to C data, what I wanted to know if there is a way to call functions expecting pointers without jumping through hoops in Haskell (like in C you would just create a variable StructA a {1,2,3}; and call function(&a);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass a reference to Haskell data to C, where the memory is allocated in the Haskell heap, and C will operate on the data directly, you need to:

- ensure it has the correct shape in memory (via a [`Storable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.0.0/doc/html/Foreign-Storable.html#t%3aStorable) instance that maps A to the an identical byte structure as `StructA`).
- allocate and fill pinned memory on the Haskell heap, via [mallocForeignPtr](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Foreign.html#v%3amallocForeignPtr)

There are several consequences to consider in this approach:

- GHC will de-allocate the value once you drop all references to the ForeignPtr -- so you will need to be sure that the C side won't touch it again
- You're letting C mess with stuff on the Haskell heap, so make sure its correct

Other options:

- pass opaque references to C via a `StablePtr`
- allocate and memory on the C side, and use a finalizer to free it.

Comment: Those are just throwaway structs used to group values together, so they aren't used after the function call anymore. I hoped there was some way to avoid having to use Storeables all the time, but I guess that's fine. Thanks!

Comment: Use `alloca` to allocate on the stack (so it is immediately cleared), and write or derive a storable instance.