# Pass haskell GC allocated data to C by pointer

Tags: haskell

After reading several wiki's and stackoverflow QA i'm left with the question how to pass mark/pass regions of memory allocated by the GC to the C library. Most of the libraries handling FFI seem to allocate memory first, copy the value into it and wrap it in a Ptr type. The problem is to get a guarantee that the memory won't be moved or deallocated while spending time in the C library.

Suppose i have a value myInput that is of type Text and i want to do zero-copy FFI with C. What are my options?

So far i've found the following:

https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface#Pointers_to_Haskell_data

> In some cases, you may want to give to the foreign code an opaque reference to a Haskell value that you will retrieve later on. You need to be sure that the value is not collected between the time you give it and the time you retrieve it. Stable pointers have been created exactly to do this. You can wrap a value into a StablePtr and give it to the foreign code (StablePtr is one of the marshallable foreign types).

After talking to some people. They tell me that the StablePtr is not supposed to be dereferenced. And is mainly used for passing void* around. On the other hand the wiki says it's suitable for this purpose and also this answer indicates the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/10900699/1833322

More information on StablePtr:

https://www.well-typed.com/blog/2018/05/ghc-special-gc-objects/

> after every GC stable pointers are updated to point to new locations of the Haskell objects that they were pointing to before the GC

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Foreign-StablePtr.html#t:StablePtr

> A stable pointer is a reference to a Haskell expression that is guaranteed not to be affected by garbage collection, i.e., it will neither be deallocated nor will the value of the stable pointer itself change during garbage collection (ordinary references may be relocated during garbage collection). Consequently, stable pointers can be passed to foreign code, which can treat it as an opaque reference to a Haskell value.

I thought i could just wrap my Text with newStablePtr http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Foreign-StablePtr.html#v:newStablePtr and be done with it. I don't understand what is now the situation with StablePtr. If i can use it for this purpose or not. And if not what is it actually used for.

Then there is pinned memory https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/GC/Pinned with ByteString

There are also pinned ByteArray http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.6.2.0/docs/Data-Primitive-ByteArray.html#g:2

Just the thing with ByteString and ByteArray is that often IO libraries provide their own data structures and data would have to be copied first INTO ByteString/ByteArray which is what i'm trying to avoid in the first place.

Maybe there are some (unsafe ?) casting functions?

It seems to be a simple problem since the GC already seems to be able to mark portions of the memory to "don't move" (pinning). Is there a function i can call on a structure to toggle this flag? Or are there any other suitable functions for this use case?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory-0.14.18/docs/Data-ByteArray.html#v:withByteArray?

Comment: What C library do you have that expects text in the form of `uint16_t *` (encoded as UTF-16)?

Comment: PCRE2 can take UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 but i'm going with UTF-16 to avoid conversion from haskell Text type.

Comment: Ah, so this is a bit of an XY problem. What are you trying to do with PCRE2?

Comment: Now it will be PCRE2, next time it will be some other thing. Don't need an explanation of the PCRE2 library and it's functions to answer the original question which is about zero-copy FFI when memory was already allocated by RTS. But if you want to dive into PCRE2 the function is pcre2_compile_16 which needs a pattern.

Comment: ... is that really the performance bottleneck? How big are your regexes?

Comment: Now it's the pattern. Guess what comes next .. the subject. The time after this it can be another C library. It doesn't matter which specific library or function, everyone doing FFI will benefit from a good answer to this question.

Comment: `StablePtr`s are not supposed to be derefenced *from C*. Calling `deRefStablePtr` is of course fine if you haven't called `freeStablePtr` yet. Neither the wiki nor the linked SO post contradict this claim in the slightest, so you may want to reread them more carefully. Another misconception: memory is not first allocated then marked as pinned. There is a separate heap for pinned memory, so no, there is not just a flag you can set; even if there were a way to "pin" an existing structure it would involve copying it into the pinned heap.

Comment: Have you looked at [Data.Text.Foreign](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.0/text-1.2.3.1/Data-Text-Foreign.html)? While this doesn't address the general case (only works for Text), it does say "The Text type is implemented using arrays that are not guaranteed to have a fixed address in the Haskell heap. All communication with native code must thus occur by copying data back and forth." So yeah, looks like you don't have any out-of-the-box options for zero-copy FFI :(.

Comment: @DanielWagner The SO posts says "To pass a reference to Haskell data to C, where the memory is allocated in the Haskell heap, and C will operate on the data directly" and gives StablePtr as a solution. Explain to me how C can operate on the data directly and not deference the pointer. Also the wiki describe giving a value to foreign code and later retrieve that value. "You need to be sure that the value is not collected between the time you give it and the time you retrieve it." foreign code is of course implicit by the whole wiki page being about FFI.

Comment: @Flip Your quote from the SO post is followed by two bullet points describing what you need to do. The two additional options listed later do not meet those needs, and are not implied to; they are alternatives to "allocate in Haskell, operate in C", not to "allocate pinned and ensure correct shape". Allocate in C and use a finalizer is an alternative to "allocate in Haskell"; `StablePtr` is an alternative to "operate in C".

Comment: @Flip The wiki describes giving a value to foreign code and later retrieving that value -- but *not retrieving it from C*. It is retrieved on the Haskell side (with `deRefStablePtr`, as described by me two comments ago).

Comment: Fwiw a `Text` that used pinned memory so you didn't have to copy, and possibly was encoded in utf-8, is a very reasonable thing to want (rust went this route). It could have been designed that way, and it would be possible to create a new library that worked like that (it might even be possible to have a package  flag that turned on allocation in pinned heap). You might consider filling an issue or proposal for the package and discussing it with the maintainers

Comment: The main issue is that supposedly/in theory a lot of pinned objects can lead to memory fragmentation

Comment: @DanielWagner what's the point of passing StablePtr in the first place when it's not supposed to be retrieved from C? If it's just a filler why not just pass nullPtr

Comment: @Flip The point is that it can be passed back from C to Haskell and dereferenced from there (whereas `nullPtr` can be passed back to Haskell but not usefully dereferenced from either side).

Comment: I'm looking to do the same. It seems copying is the only solution for now?

I tried dereferencing a StablePtr inside C and got a SIGSEGV 11. Notably, the address of the stableptr was 0x1b.

Comment: @cmspice this works https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory-0.15.0/docs/Data-ByteArray.html#t:ByteArrayAccess but you still need to encode/decode when you come or go to other types like Text for example. However i'm not putting this as my own answer because i would like more understanding or control over how pinning works in the garbage collector

Comment: Thanks @flip. I think that also only works when calling C from Haskell and not the other way (at least without using a function ptr to call back into C).

Comment: Following up on my own comment: I read docs more carefully on StablePtr. Though the reference says that StablePtrs should pin the underlying value (it doesn't say specifically "pin" though), it makes no guarantees about the memory address and in particular, may not even be a valid memory (and hence SIGSEGV). That's fine and all. It's a little weird they call them "Ptrs" and even offer the "castStablePtrToPtr" function.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Foreign-StablePtr.html

Comment: The reference to ByteArrayAcces is a mistake by me, you don't get a guarantee with this typeclass. However .. wether haskell calls C or C calls haskell is not the interesting part. It's wether haskell or C allocates the data you want to work with. I think StablePtr works so that the address of the pointer itself is guaranteed to stay the same, but what it points to can be changed by haskell as it wants. Therefor you can use this pointer in C to pass from and to haskell, but not access the data of this pointer because the location can change by the GC while you are accessing it.